# When wi-fi is tuned off, status shows NotReachable but when wi-fi turned on again network status still shows NotReachable

Tags: ios, reachability

I've this scenario, UIViewController => UITableViewController => UITableViewController  => UIViewController.

From first UITableViewController, I check internet connection and populate data based on that.

This is what the problem is -
1. At first UITableViewController wi-fi is on so data populated from URL, 
2. I turn-off wi-fi and select row and go to second UITableViewController, network status is NotReachable and data is populated from database
3. I turn on wi-fi and select row and go to last UIViewcontroller, **here network status is NotReachable whereas it should be ReachableViaWiFi**

Am I missing something? Please suggest.

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                                 selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                     name: kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                                   object: nil];
        Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname: @"www.apple.com"];
        [reach startNotifier];
    }


    - (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability *reach = [notification object];
    if( [reach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]) {
        NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
        switch(status) {
            case NotReachable:
            {
                if (!performedOnce) {
                    [self processOffline];
                    performedOnce = YES;
                }
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
            }
                break;
            default:
            {
                if (!performedOnce) {
                    [self retrieveUserListWithUrl];
                    performedOnce = YES;
                }
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```